# How can I log grpc status in Nginx access log?

Tags: nginx, grpc, http2

I want to log grpc status code in Nginx access log
tried

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $http_grpc_status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

but not working Nginx will only log http status code not grpc_status

Answer (score 0):

### * What do you mean? GRPCS status?

#### You already tried this

- Make file log:

  - nano /var/log/nginx/[filelog].log
- [Close and save]
- try this in the .conf

#### out server directive

log_format  prog3  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" $server_port $scheme';

#### in server directive

server {
....
access_log /var/log/nginx/[filelog].log prog3;

- And execute nginx in mode debug

  - Stop nginx
  - /etc/init.d/nginx stop
- Run nginx-debug

  - /etc/init.d/nginx-debug start

Comment: i dislike the formatting, and readability of response. Also the question was about grpc status